# Como sumar el total dentro de un array de objetos - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el array movies, y el output esperado esperado es un array [420] con el total de duracion por los 3 objetos dentro de array, Cómo puedo hacer esto con la funcion reduce?

Me aparecen los 3 numeros concatenados como string:

```js
let movies = [
  {
    'name': 'Jumanji',
    'duration': 120
  },
  {
    'name': 'Harry',
    'duration': 60
  },
  {
    'name': 'Toy Story',
    'duration': 240
  }
];

let newAr = movies.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => 
[ previousValue + currentValue.duration ], []);

console.log('newAr', newAr)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sucede que estás intentando aplicar directamente el método reduce sobre objetos.

Una forma de resolver el problema es obtener previamente un `Array` que contenga los valores del campo `duration` de cada objeto de tu `Array`.

Por ejemplo, podrías encadenar el método [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para obtener el `Array` con los valores de `duration` y luego aplicar el método `reduce()` a este resultado:

```js
let movies = [
  {
    'name': 'Jumanji',
    'duration': 120
  },
  {
    'name': 'Harry',
    'duration': 60
  },
  {
    'name': 'Toy Story',
    'duration': 240
  }
];

// envolvemos los métodos en [] si deseamos un array
let newAr = [movies
.map(obj => obj.duration)
.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  return prev + curr
})];

console.log('newAr', newAr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 4):

¿Por qué pones `[]` como valor inicial de `reduce()`? Si vas a sumar, entonces debe ser número (cero).

¿Por qué encierras la suma entre corchetes `[ previousValue + currentValue.duration ]`? Eso hace que devuelva un arreglo en lugar de solo la operación.

```js
let movies = [
  {
    'name': 'Jumanji',
    'duration': 120
  },
  {
    'name': 'Harry',
    'duration': 60
  },
  {
    'name': 'Toy Story',
    'duration': 240
  }
];

let newAr = movies.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) =>
    // Solo realiza la suma, sin encerrar entre corchetes []
    previousValue + currentValue.duration,
0); // Este parámetro establece el valor inicial para reduce(), debe ser cero

console.log('newAr', newAr)
```